# jasper and timestamp conversion in stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, jasperserver

i created a stored procedure. inside that i'm comparing timestamps this way "sum(case when t.tsmax > to_timestamp(to_char(t.tinmax + epeff,''ddMMyyyy'')||tout,''dd.MM.yyyy HH24:MI:SS'') then anzsend end)". calling that procedure from Oracle SQL Developer works fine (total 25044). calling it from jasersoft studio on my local desktop works perfect as well (total 25044).
but when invoking it on Jasperserver i'm not getting the same result (total 13054). it looks like it has something to do with NLS settings. session language in SQL Developer and jasperosft is German, running it on jasperserver uses American. i tried things like to_timestamp(...,'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=GERMAN'or('NSL_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT=dd.MM.yyyy...')) or use other formats, but with no success. tsmax and tinmax are read from a global temporary table, maybe there i something wronng.any idea? i really need help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

works fine after altering NLS_TERRITORY from AMERICA to GERMANY for the session.